# Function returns table, get records as columns when using a set of params

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a function, which takes two parameters, `year` and `month`, declared like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(
    _year integer,
    _month integer)
RETURNS TABLE (
    column_1 integer,
    column_2 text
) AS
$$
BEGIN
-- Do somenthing here and return the data...
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I know that if I want to get the result of the function call as separate columns, I have to call it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(2018, 7);
```

However, I would like to make a more complex call, like this:

```
SELECT my_function(year, month)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM generate_series('2017-01-01', now(), interval '1 month'))::integer AS year,
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM generate_series('2017-01-01', now(), interval '1 month'))::integer AS month
) sub;
```

This results in a set of `record` type rows. How can I get the "proper" table row format when specifying my parameters like this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT j.year, j.month FROM 
(
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM generate_series('2017-01-01', now(), interval '1 month'))::integer AS year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM generate_series('2017-01-01', now(), interval '1 month'))::integer AS month
) t
JOIN LATERAL my_function(year, month) j(year, month)
on true
```